# Vault csi provider in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, vault, csi

I'm trying to run Vault CSI provider but I'm getting the following error in my app pod:

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod vault/my-service-9b78df688-8xnql, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error making mount request: failed to login: Error making API request. Namespace: vault URL: POST https://vault.craft-code.com/v1/auth/gcp/login Code: 400. Errors: * unable to get public key for signed JWT: unable to get public key "xxxxx" for JWT subject "system:serviceaccount:vault:service-web-app": googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.

According to the doc, before login to vault google cloud should issue jwt credential to be able to login in vault. I'm ussing terraform but I don't know how to do that. Could something explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Once the service account and key have been created, the private key can be used to generate the JWT token needed to login to Vault.

To configure a Google Cloud service account to issue a JWT token before it can be used to login to Vault, you need to complete the [following](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/auth/gcp) steps:

- Create a service account in the Google Cloud platform.
- Download the JSON key file associated with the service account.
- Configure the Vault server to use the GCP auth backend and provide
  the JSON key file for the service account.
- Configure the Google Cloud IAM roles for the service account in order
  to grant it access to the Vault server.
- Get the JWT token from the service account and use it to authenticate
  with Vault.

Refer to this [doc](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/csi) also

Comment: Hey! I had created a service account and configured the vault server to use gcp auth. In fact, it is working with that service account at least using the cli vault login. The problem is that I created another service account (for the app scope) and this one can login to vault using the cli vault login but not using the api. Because the csi provider pod is calling trying to login using the api.

Comment: This might be due to either an invalid or expired token, or an incorrect scope or permission set on the service account.check the scope and permissions set on the service account to ensure that it has the necessary access to authenticate with Vault. Refer this [setup vault plugin](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-auth-gcp#set-up-plugin-in-vault) and its service account permissions.